# Create a general (not field specific) error message for the form in Play (Scala) framework

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I can create a custom field-specific error message like so:

```
Form(form.mapping, Map(), Seq(FormError("postcode", "Not recognised")), None)))
```

How to create a custom general error message for the form rather than for a specific field?  Something like:

```
Form(form.mapping, Map(), Seq(FormError(None, "Could not send")), None)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a global error, which is just a `FormError` with no key (an empty `String` since it's not an `Option`). `Form` has a method called `withGlobalError` in which you can pass an error message and other arguments. In your case if you have some `Form`:

```
val form: Form[?] = ???

form.withGlobalError("Could not send")
```

`withGlobalError` simply calls `withError`, which is roughly equivalent to your second snippet, though it eventually does a `copy` on the `Form` instead. You can also see the [source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/0179b30f21439594e748af80aca14c10cffa148f/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L260).

In the context of your example it would look like this:

```
Form(form.mapping, Map(), Seq(FormError("", "Could not send")), None)))
```

Comment: Thanks @m-z :) A long shot but don't suppose you know why the empty `String` is used instead of `Option`?

Comment: @bjfletcher A design choice. The `key` represents a sort of path in the form mapping. Like if you have an address nested inside a contact, you might have `"contact.address.street"`. The empty string just represents the root path.